# Build failed for AWS Amplify React Site for unknown reason

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, yarnpkg, aws-amplify

TL;DR: I can't tell why my React app is failing the build on AWS Amplify.

Hello! I am new to deploying with AWS Amplify and needed some help demystifying the below logs.

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: yarn install
2020-09-14T02:09:01.005Z [INFO]: yarn install v1.16.0
2020-09-14T02:09:01.102Z [INFO]: [1/4] Resolving packages...
2020-09-14T02:09:01.572Z [INFO]: [2/4] Fetching packages...
2020-09-14T02:09:16.267Z [INFO]: info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
                                 info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2020-09-14T02:09:16.275Z [INFO]: info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
                                 info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2020-09-14T02:09:16.276Z [INFO]: info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2020-09-14T02:09:16.278Z [INFO]: info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2020-09-14T02:09:16.284Z [INFO]: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2020-09-14T02:09:16.286Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-bootstrap-switch@15.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.5.0".
2020-09-14T02:09:23.129Z [INFO]: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2020-09-14T02:09:25.051Z [INFO]: Done in 24.05s.
2020-09-14T02:09:25.072Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
2020-09-14T02:09:25.073Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: yarn run build
2020-09-14T02:09:25.229Z [INFO]: yarn run v1.16.0
2020-09-14T02:09:25.257Z [INFO]: $ react-scripts build && gulp licenses
2020-09-14T02:09:26.114Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2020-09-14T02:09:40.526Z [INFO]: Compiled successfully.
2020-09-14T02:09:40.527Z [INFO]: File sizes after gzip:
2020-09-14T02:09:40.550Z [INFO]: 57.07 KB  build/static/js/2.57db696b.chunk.js
2020-09-14T02:09:40.552Z [INFO]: 46.8 KB   build/static/css/main.b7a04f59.chunk.css
                                 5.82 KB   build/static/js/main.34e0f1c3.chunk.js
                                 779 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.58837106.js
                                 The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./.
                                 You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
                                 The build folder is ready to be deployed.
                                 Find out more about deployment here:
                                 bit.ly/CRA-deploy
2020-09-14T02:09:40.864Z [INFO]: [02:09:40]
2020-09-14T02:09:40.864Z [INFO]: Using gulpfile /codebuild/output/src019925290/src/harsh_electronics_site/gulpfile.js
2020-09-14T02:09:40.865Z [INFO]: [02:09:40]
2020-09-14T02:09:40.866Z [INFO]: Starting 'licenses'...
2020-09-14T02:09:40.876Z [INFO]: [02:09:40]
2020-09-14T02:09:40.876Z [INFO]: Finished 'licenses' after 10 ms
2020-09-14T02:09:40.903Z [INFO]: Done in 15.68s.
2020-09-14T02:09:40.907Z [INFO]: # Executing command: node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
2020-09-14T02:09:41.148Z [INFO]: [02:09:41]
2020-09-14T02:09:41.149Z [INFO]: Using gulpfile /codebuild/output/src019925290/src/harsh_electronics_site/gulpfile.js
2020-09-14T02:09:41.149Z [WARNING]: [02:09:41]
2020-09-14T02:09:41.149Z [WARNING]: Task never defined: default
                                    [02:09:41] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks
2020-09-14T02:09:41.153Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2020-09-14T02:09:41.153Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2020-09-14T02:09:41.154Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2020-09-14T02:09:41.154Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

The only two error lines occur almost at the very end, but I cannot immediately identify why. The React site loads just fine on my local computer using `yarn start` and I also don't see any failures locally with `yarn build`. Any ideas?

Here's the gulpfile.js if it helps:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gap = require("gulp-append-prepend");

gulp.task("licenses", async function () {
  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified js
  gulp
    .src("build/static/js/*chunk.js", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`/*!

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

*/`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));

  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified html
  gulp
    .src("build/index.html", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`<!--

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

-->`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));

  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified css
  gulp
    .src("build/static/css/*chunk.css", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`/*!

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

*/`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));
  return;
});
```

Comment: looks like it's running an gulp file with the `default` task that is not defined. Can you share it here? `/codebuild/output/src019925290/src/harsh_electronics_site/gulpfile.js`

Comment: Sure! Just edited the original questions and added `gulpfile.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your gulpfile to this. I just added an alias for a `default` task.

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gap = require("gulp-append-prepend");

async function license() {
  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified js
  gulp
    .src("build/static/js/*chunk.js", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`/*!

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

*/`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));

  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified html
  gulp
    .src("build/index.html", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`<!--

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

-->`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));

  // this is to add Creative Tim licenses in the production mode for the minified css
  gulp
    .src("build/static/css/*chunk.css", { base: "./" })
    .pipe(
      gap.prependText(`/*!

=========================================================
* Paper Kit React - v1.2.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react
* Copyright 2020 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

* Coded by HarshElectronics

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

*/`)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./", { overwrite: true }));
  return;
}

gulp.task("licenses", license);
gulp.task("default", license);
```

Comment: This made it work! Thank you so much! In summary, what was originally wrong? Where did the need to define the 'default' task come from?

Comment: No idea why your workflow required a default task. I just followed the error and created an alias :)