# Amplify build fails with ReferenceError: license is not defined

Tags: reactjs, npm, gulp, aws-amplify

Original error was `Task never defined: default` and asked/answered here:
[Build failed for AWS Amplify React Site for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63877308/build-failed-for-aws-amplify-react-site-for-unknown-reason)

Now I get this error:

```
2022-04-10T16:04:21.976Z [WARNING]: ReferenceError: license is not defined
                                at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src885439336/src/pn-toolbox-react/gulpfile.js:80:23)
                                at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
                                at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
                                at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
                                at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
                                at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
                                at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
                                at requireOrImport (/codebuild/output/src885439336/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js:19:11)
                                at execute (/codebuild/output/src885439336/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js:37:3)
                                at Liftoff.handleArguments (/codebuild/output/src885439336/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:211:24)
```

The license is for Creative Tim components.
This builds successfully on my local system.

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` file you need to add a `license` value.

For example:

```
{
  "license" : "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>"
}
```

Comment: ah, got it. trying this now.

Comment: didn't fix it for me but I think my issue is not related to the gulp.js file. I removed it and still get that error even with the license file in place and linked in package.json. I have reached out to CreativeTim support about this.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, good luck man!